# Which antivirus software can detect very old (1998+) viruses?

Tags: antivirus

I am building a retro PC and I am going to install a lot of game patches which I downloaded on different sites on the internet.

I want to scan these files on a **modern** PC. Then I want to install them on the retro PC.

That's why I am looking for a antivirus software which can detect very old viruses (1998 and newer). The software does **not** have to run on an old PC.

Which antivirus do you recommand? It should be for Windows or Linux.

I found this post: [Free lightweight Antivirus for old computers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/53749/free-lightweight-antivirus-for-old-computers)

But it is about running an antivirus program on old PCs and not about scanning old files on a modern PC.

Comment: I would expect modern Antivirus programs to still contain the signatures of old viruses, do you expect that not to be the case?

Comment: @kutschkem I do because such a signature does not take much space. But I want to be sure. Many antivirus Programm like Windows Defender didn't  even exist in 1998.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uploaded a virus called Happy1999 from 1999 to virustotal.com and it shows that almost all modern antivirus programs detect it. I also uploaded the Pikachu worm from 2000 and it's also detected by most programs.

[Happy1999 result on virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/4ebe3e1af5e147c580ecce052fe7d7d0219d5e5a2f5e6d8a7f7291735923db18)

[Pikachu worm result von virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/e1dfc005d5403fb2f356276f0abe19df68249ce10e5035450926d56c2f8d3652)

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Web v. < 5.45 with all updates
if it doesn't install on modern OS, use VirtualBox and a legacy WinXP iso image